# CakePHP: variable sources for virtual field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Each Order has fields 'from_str' and 'from_bldg'.
In Order model I created virtual field "from" that concatenates these fields:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
   'from' => 'CONCAT(Order.from_str, " ", Order.from_bldg)'
);
```

However, Order has also a link to a Company. So, if field from_company_id is not 0/null, I would like to show Company's name inside "from" field in Order.

For example:

Order1 has `from_str = "Baker st"`, `from_bld = "221B"`, and `from_company_id = "0"`
Order2 has `from_str` and `from_bld null`, but `from_company_id = "1"`

Company with id = 1 has name "Sun, Inc."

So, for Order1's "from" field I would like to have "Baker st 221B",
and for Order2's "from" field I would like to get "Sun, Inc."

What would model's or controller's code look like to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Company info (street, name, building) is stored in a separate database table (e.g. `companies`) and should be shown together with the order if the `id` matches `from_company_id`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have separate Companies table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a relation between both models. Since you did not name the foreign key according to the CakePHP conventions (i.e. `company_id`), you will have to specify that yourself.

app/Model/Order.php

```
class Order extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'from_company_id',
        )
    );
}
```

app/Model/Company.php

```
class Company extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'from_company_id',
        )
    );
}
```

And, inside your controller;

```
$order = $this->Order->find('first, array(
    'conditions' => array(
       'Order.id' => $id,  // or whatever name the ID has
    ),
    'recursive' => 1,
));

debug($order);
```

This should give you both the **Order** *and* the **'Company'** details. **However**, the *company* details will be in a separate 'key' ('Company') inside the `$order` array. If this is just for outputting the order in your view, I don't see a reason to use a virtualField to merge the data to the 'Order' key inside the array.

If merging the data to the same key is an important requirement, please describe your requirements, then I may assist you further

Comment: thaJeztah, thanks so much!!
relationship between models solved everything! =)
no i can access all company info from $order.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project. If this is a new project, please try to stick with the CakePHP conventions when naming your database fields and tables, this will save you a lot of problems and configuration. Read the documentation here [Model Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)